# Magento: filters from category left also display in our home left menu

Tags: magento

so I am changing code in catalog.xml

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
<label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_category_default>



<catalog_category_default translate="label">
<label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
<reference name="left">
<!--  <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>-->
 <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

I want to add filter layer left in our template home.phtml but its not working
I am also add block in home.phtml admin cms design but it's not working so any one tell 
What can i do??

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if there is a block with name "currency" in the left? As this code tells Magento to add it after the block named currency.

Maybe try the below which will put it first.

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Can you try putting it in layout update tab for the home page
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>